# Optimizing js -Saving values from checkboxes in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, design-patterns, checkbox

i'm rather new to js and i'd like to optimize my code.
I have a group of checkboxes and their boolean values are saved in an object for further calculations.

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" onchange="checkbox1Changed()" value="checkbox1">

    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" onchange="checkbox2Changed()" value="checkbox2">

    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" onchange="checkbox3Changed()" value="checkbox3">
</fieldset>
```

JS:

```
//store values for further computation

var boxValues = {
    box1: false,
    box2: false,
    box3: false,
}

//get checkboxvalues from view

var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("checkbox2");
var checkbox3 = document.getElementById("checkbox3");

//update values in boxValues

function checkbox1Changed() {
    if (checkbox1.checked) {
        boxValues.box1 = true;
    } else {
        boxValues.box1 = false;
    }
}

function checkbox2Changed() {
    if (checkbox2.checked) {
        boxValues.box2 = true;
    } else {
        boxValues.box2 = false;
    }
}

function checkbox3Changed() {
    if (checkbox3.checked) {
        boxValues.box3 = true;
    } else {
        boxValues.box3 = false;
    }
}
```

Since i plan on having approximately 20 checkboxes in the view there would be a lot of repeating code. 
Does anyone know a smarter way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Vin

Comment: Are you actually using jquery or did you add that tag by accident/habit? If you aren't using it you don't need to add it just for this code, but you might want to remove the tag so you don't get answers that assume you already use jQuery.

Comment: If jquery serves the purpose i dont mind using it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add **common class** to all the checkboxes
2. Create an object for the values of all checkboxes
3. Bind event handler on the checkboxes using the **common class**
4. Update the status of clicked checkbox in event handler

Also, it is good practice to bind events in javascript instead of inline in the HTML.

```js
var myObj = {
  checkbox1: false,
  checkbox2: false,
  checkbox3: false
};
$('.myCheckbox').on('change', function() {
  var thisId = $(this).attr('id');

  myObj[thisId] = this.checked;

  console.log(myObj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="checkbox1" class="myCheckbox">

  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="checkbox2" class="myCheckbox">

  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="checkbox3" class="myCheckbox">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: thanks, it works! what do i need the field "value" for in this solution?
Or can i remove it since "id" is used?

Comment: @VinBanton To get the `value`, you can use `$(this).val()` in the event handler

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the same function to every checkbox, and use the id of the checkbox as the key in your object:

```
function onCheckBoxChanged(e){
  var sender = e.target;
  boxValues[sender.id] = (sender.checked);
}
```

Playing around with this should save you a lot of typing :)